# MVC Multiple Forms and Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I assume that it is not possible to do this because I cannot get it to work and despite reading nearly every resource I could find.  I have a form, actually a partial view, with three separate forms in it:

```
 <div  id="divTypePage" style="display:none" class="admin">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Type", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "typeForm" }))
{
    <h4>Item Type Maintenance</h4>
    <table class="table_body">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b style="color:red">*</b>Find Item Type or Enter New Code:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="types" style="text-transform:uppercase" class="typeModel" />
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypeCode, new {@id = "txtTypeCode"})
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b style="color:red">*</b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypeDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypeDescription, new { @id = "txtDesc", style="text-transform:uppercase", @class="typeModel" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypeDescription)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypePriority)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypePriority, new { @id = "txtPrior", @maxLength = "1", style = "width: 50px", @class="typeModel" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.ItemTypeModel.ItemTypePriority)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
  </div>
      <div id="divRolePage" style="display:none" class="admin">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Role", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "roleForm" }))
{
    <h4>Role Maintenance</h4>
    <table class="table_body">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b style="color:red">*</b>Find Role or Enter New:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="roles" class="roleModel" style="text-transform:uppercase" />
                @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Role, new { @id = "txtRole"})
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b style="color:red">*</b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Description, new { @id = "txtRoleDesc", style = "text-transform:uppercase", @class = "roleModel"})
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Admin)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Admin, new { @id = "chkAdmin"})
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Trans)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Trans, new { @id = "chkTrans"})
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Reports)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.RoleModel.Reports, new { @id = "chkReports"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
   </div>
```

I open each one by using a dialog, which I am not gonna show.  But it is like this:

```
 function OpenAdminPage(page) {
    var type = page;
    switch (page) {
        case "type":
            $("#divTypePage").dialog("open");
            ParseForm("#typeForm");
            break;
        case "user":
            ClearValues();
            $("#divUserPage").dialog("open");
            ParseForm("#userForm");
            break;
        case "role":
            ClearValues();
            $("#divRolePage").dialog("open");
            ParseForm("#roleForm");
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the function is this:

```
 function ParseForm(selector) {
var form = $(selector)
    .removeData("Validator")
    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
}
```

However, only one form will display errors, the other two are giving me this:

```
0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character
```

This in jquery-1.11.2 in the jQuery.parseJSON function.  Am I just doing this wrong or is it not possible to do this way?

Comment: Can you break the forms up more and see if it still happens? Have your trying moving them out of partial views to troubleshoot? Putting them in there own partial views?

Comment: What if you use `body` as selector (just for debugging purposes). Will it find, and bind, to the other forms then? The _unobtrusive.parse()_ will look for form elements with attributes `data-val=true`, are these present on all elements?

Comment: Can you parse by class?  If I set a class for each set of inputs, will this work?

Comment: @Mackan - actually when I view source on the page I don't see any of the elements in the DIVs that are the three forms, nonetheless the attributes.  These DIVs are display:none.

Comment: You can view them in the development console/inspector if you open a dialogue at a time (or all for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any MVC validation code visible in the example you posted for *roleForm*. A bit thin assumption, but I'm basing this on the following:

> When an input field has any client side validation rule attached to it, it will receive the data-val="true" attribute to trigger unobtrusive client validation.

Data annotations and validation messages will create the "missing" attributes (well, assumed missing at this point). I'm sure you know how these work since you got one form validation working, but for reference:

In the model:

```
public class MyModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "What is my name?")]
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.MyName)
```

Why this would throw a javascript error is a bit unclear. But I hope the above will fix it anyway.

Edit - [A good reference (mainly for MVC3, but it applies)](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Comment: Yeah, that was before I put the required atts in.  Anyway, it still does not work and I get the same JS error.  It is driving me crazy!  So I removed the JS check - if (!$("#roleForm").valid()) - and just captured the errors in the controller.  Pain but had to be done.

Answer (score -2):

using JSON.parse(data) . it is serialize in correct way. and one more clarification. if you are hosting your application in iis. please do followings:

open IIS and look at your MIME types. Check to see if you have one called .json. If not, simply add one called .json and set it to application/json.